# React 0.14: plain object replacement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React doc you can find the next breaking changes:

`Plain objects are no longer supported as React children; arrays should be used instead. You can use the createFragment helper to migrate, which now returns an array.`

**Who can explain what does they mean by plain objects?**

There are two ways to create component: ES6 `extends React.Component` & `React.createClass`. *Which of them is plain?*

Comment: That's not what this error is talking about (which is honestly a bit confusing). Check out https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/create-fragment.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, you could use both arrays of components as children:

```
var arr = [
  <div>one</div>,
  <div>two</div>
];

return <div>{arr}</div>;
```

and objects with component values as children:

```
var obj = {
  one: <div>one</div>,
  two: <div>two</div>
};

return <div>{obj}</div>;
```

React would iterate the keys and display each component. That is no longer supported.

In many cases, this just means you're accidentally rendering an object when you mean to render a string or something else.

Answer (score 1):

In the docs they mention `createFragment`

> You can use the createFragment helper to migrate, which now returns an array.

Which has a link to the `createFragment` docs which explains how to not render plain objects, but instead use their helper method to create that object

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/create-fragment.html

That means you just can't render plain objects in your render function. It looks like it has nothing to do with `React.component` or `React.createClass` which I assume both still can be used.